# Checking Network Load Balancing (NLB) and IIS programatically in C#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, asp.net-4.0, nlb

I intend to write a small program to check IIS service connectivity and statistics through multiple connections in parallel. The IIS service is behind NLB service (and there 3 different service). So what I did so far is:

1. Create an http handler that returns the name of the current IIS server.
2. Create small HTTP client in WinForms application that sends a request to the NLB. In this client: a series of 100 parallel requests through WebClient object is being sent to the NLB service.

Results: When I send the requests to the NLB, always single IIS server responses. When I try to change the URI to the IIS servers specifically - every server responses on its own request. Now, I think that it means that the NLB doesn't do what it is supposed to do, since it navigates always to the same server (for every run, single server answers - it can change, but not for the run).

Is the check that I mention credible for checking NLB?
If not, how can I check it through Winforms application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the requests clones? Do they have quick responses?

Comment: They have quick responses, but they are not clones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is typical behaviour of NLB. It will try and give you the same host each time. You don't want it to pick a random server each time.

You will have much more useful information from examining the IIS Server logs, performance counters or in built monitoring routines.

Comment: I thought that every request is handled on its own, when talking about stateless applications... It cannot be that for 15 minutes of sending requests - every time the same IIS server responses. It means that the NLB doesn't navigate and redirect through which server is the most available, if it were about balancing.

Comment: Do you think I need to put sleep() on the http handler, to make the server less available for checking purposes?

Comment: No it would be a useless test, IIS would probably queue the requests anyway. NLB relates to the machines network connection not IIS availablity to serve the responses. You'd be better rebooting one of the servers while you run your test.

Comment: Is there any way to make the (single) computer that runs the test application impersonate itself as other computers, so to make NLB and IIS somewhat more appropiate for the test? 
This is like mulptiple requests from other computers and will check what I was required to check... I can't believe there is no way to know how NLB reacts in production fo rmultiple requests. Microsoft Windows Server 2008 has no built-in counters for NLB navigations. So I want to create an spplication that counts it and creates a statistical report for NLB performance.

Comment: Yes - you use a technique called IP Spoofing, a purpose built app can configure a computer to use many ip address and spoof request from each. This is usually best left to Network Engineers! - There are a few tools that can do it for you. VS2010 has the Load Test Pack - that's a pay for bolt on from MS. There are others listed here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/load-test-virtual-user-pack/overview As this is server related you may want to try asking on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Can I commit spoofing in C#, in runtime, without saving or changing TCP/IP settings of the local computer?

Comment: One of the issues we have is that Windows Server NLB doesn't register concurrent sessions (from clients and to IIS server). It's true that I can see it through the IIS servers, but what happens if some tried to get dirctly and not through NLB... I'll miss that. I read Wikipedia's before getting to Stackoverflw. Also, other NLBs, such as Cisco's, have the same issue... I guess I'll need a miracle to get the Application done :-) ...

Comment: Require the URL used to access the site contain the name of the NLB address and not the machine names or ip address.

Comment: Won't work... That's exactly what I did - and the NLB always navigates to the same IIS server. We've decided to only check the IIS servers directly, its web services and the NLB directly (and not the navigation).

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Affinity setting` in NLB manager.

Change this setting from single to None and check the request is going to different server each time.